# Updating Access Database with Visual Basic(2017) textfield

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, com-interop

I'm working on a simple billing program for my father in law and the Access database is not updating. I built the connection and query inside of a try catch block but the database still won't update outside of it. I know it's probably something simple but I just can't see it. What am I missing?

```
'Database Connection
Dim Connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; User ID=Admin; Data Source =MBPDatabase.mdb;"
Dim MBP As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Connection)

MBP.Open()
Dim sqlJob As String

sqlJob = "INSERT INTO Jobs ([jobID], [jobClients], [jobName], [jobPrice])
     VALUES("",@jobClients,@jobName,0.00)"

Dim Job As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlJob, MBP)

Job.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("jobClients", txtClient.Text))
Job.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("jobName", txtJobName.Text))

Job.ExecuteNonQuery()

MBP.Close()
```

Comment: Where's the try/catch block, and is it just swallowing the exception or reporting it in any way? Is there an exception? What's the error? Is `JobID` a `String` field? Because I would expect it to be an `int` / `AutoNumber`; I suspect you're getting (and swallowing) an exception that says everything you need to know about fixing this error.

Comment: Actually, the query you're sending is `INSERT... VALUES(",@jobClients,@jobName,0.00)` - notice the double quotes there: that's *definitely* giving you an exception on `Job.ExecuteNonQuery()`. You need these double quotes properly escaped - assuming an empty string is a legit value for the `jobID` field.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely the double qoute for `jobID` after the `VALUES`-keyword.

This leads to the following result (one double qoute):

```
...VALUES(",@jobClients,@jobName,0.00)
```

Change it to this (two single quotes):

```
sqlJob = "...VALUES('',@jobClients,@jobName,0.00)"
```

Comment: Arguably OP also needs to understand how to use a `Try / Catch` block for their own sake, too. I'm 99.9% sure the exception message says quite exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Agree, the exception message will surely tell what's wrong. The double quote-thing was just the most obvious thing i saw at first sight.

Comment: Ah yes, ill add the try/catch block. Thanks for the suggestion. Btw I have an empty value because jobID is an auto number value inside the table (PK). Do I need to add a value to that field?

Comment: To get Access to provide the ID, leave the JobID field out of the list or insert NULL for the JobID column value.